# How do I check my available storage in Yahoo Mail?

Tags: yahoo-mail

I want to know how much I have used from my storage and how much I have left. Where can I see that?

Comment: Yahoo has now limited to 1 Terabyte.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yahoo! Mail features **unlimited** storage.

From here: http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/yahoomail/tools/tools-08.html